# Being a freelancer

Tags: freelance-websites

Being a freelancer is realy harder than finding a job XD
Im a webdeveloper and im looking / trying to have a job (via the internet)
(Not Complicated stuff! just websites like  a small store  etc )

can any one tell me how can i get started?

Comment: A similar but perhaps not entirely duplicate question asked previously that I answered can be found here: http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/4279/how-to-find-good-jobs-on-freelancing-sites/4416#4416

Comment: Hello Achraf, and welcome to Freelancing.SE! — unfortunately, "How do I get started" is just way, way too broad to be answerable in a format that we use on Stack Exchange. Could you please [edit] your question to be more specific, so we can clean it up and provide better answers?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, one of the best sites to start freelancing is [Freelancer](http://freelancer.com/). I am on this site, and it is awesome. I get a lot of work from here. Be sure to check it out :)

Comment: already in there but for a started! its impossible this days i guess (i know that i can get things done but i dont have a 5 star profile you know)

Comment: It's not impossible, you just have to bid on a lot of projects. My tips are: 1. Be honest 2. Upgrade your membership, so you can bid on more jobs.

Comment: if i had the means to upgrade , i wouldnt be looking for a job XD 3rd world country problemes, any way thanks man :D ill keep trying

Comment: Why the downvotes? It would be nice to explain them before downvoting.

Answer (score -1):

There are several options out there. But I would recommend you ELANCE (Upwork), I have got many jobs there.

Consider to have a nice portfolio, so the clients can see how good you are.